# Determine whether each character in the first string can be uniquely replaced by a character in the second string so that the two strings are equal

Tags: c#, arrays, string, algorithm, sorting

Give two strings of equal size. Determine whether each character in the first string can be uniquely replaced by a character in the second string so that the two strings are equal. Display also the corresponding character pairs between the two strings. The code works well now.

Example 1:

For input data:

```
aab
ttd
```

The console will display:

```
True
a => t
b => d
```

Example 2:

For input data:

```
tab
ttd
```

The console will display:

```
False
```

In the second example the answer is false because there is no unique correspondence for the character 'a': both 't' and 'd' correspond to it.

This is my code:

```
using System;
```

namespace problemeJM
{
class Program
{
static void Main(string[] args)
{
string firstPhrase = Convert.ToString(Console.ReadLine());
string secondPhrase = Convert.ToString(Console.ReadLine());
string aux1 = string.Empty, aux2 = string.Empty;
bool x = true;

```
        for (int i = 0; i < firstPhrase.Length; i++)
        {
            if (!aux1.Contains(firstPhrase[i]))
            {
                aux1 += firstPhrase[i];
            }
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < secondPhrase.Length; i++)
        {
            if (!aux2.Contains(secondPhrase[i]))
            {
                aux2 += secondPhrase[i];
            }
        }
        if (aux1.Length != aux2.Length)
        {
            
            Console.WriteLine("False");
            
        }
        else
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < firstPhrase.Length - 2; i++)
            {
                for (int j = 1; j < secondPhrase.Length - 1; j++)
                {
                    if (firstPhrase[i] == firstPhrase[j] && secondPhrase[i] == secondPhrase[j])
                    {
                        x = true;
                    }
                    else if (firstPhrase[i] != firstPhrase[j] && secondPhrase[i] != secondPhrase[j])
                    {
                        x = true;
                    }
                    else if (firstPhrase[i] == firstPhrase[j] && secondPhrase[i] != secondPhrase[j])
                    {
                        x = false;
                        break;
                    }
                    else if (firstPhrase[i] != firstPhrase[j] && secondPhrase[i] == secondPhrase[j])
                    {
                        x = false;
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
        
        
        Console.WriteLine(x);
        aux1 = string.Empty;
        aux2 = string.Empty;
        if (x == true)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < firstPhrase.Length; i++)
            {
                if (!aux1.Contains(firstPhrase[i]))
                {
                    aux1 += firstPhrase[i];
                }
            }
            for (int i = 0; i < secondPhrase.Length; i++)
            {
                if (!aux2.Contains(secondPhrase[i]))
                {
                    aux2 += secondPhrase[i];
                }
            }

            for (int i = 0; i <= aux1.Length - 1; i++)
            {
                for (int j = 1; j <= aux2.Length; j++)
                {
                    if (aux1[i] == aux1[j] && aux2[i] == aux2[j])
                    {

                        Console.WriteLine(aux1[i] + " => " + aux2[i]);
                        break;
                    }
                    else if (aux1[i] != aux1[j] && aux2[i] != aux2[j])
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine(aux1[i] + " => " + aux2[i]);
                        break;
                    }
                 }
              }
            }
        }           
    }    
}
```

}

Comment: I think I'd do this with a dictionary; step the two arrays at the same time,  filling the dictionary with array1char as the key and array2char as the value. If ever I'm adding something that already exists (Hint; TryGetValue or ContainsKey before you add and change behavior accordingly) then it is mandatory that the Value that is there already shall be the same as the current array2char, otherwise exit the loop early and return false. If get to the end of the loop then return a true. The dictionary contains the mappings you will print if it is true. Seems like homework;not going to code it,GL!

Comment: Hint: Use `Dictionary<char, char>`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should use a `Dictionary<char, char>` as commented. But you need to check if there's a unique mapping in both string, so from s1 to s2 and from s2 to s1:

```
static bool UniqueMapping(string s1, string s2)
{
    int length = Math.Min(s1.Length, s2.Length);
    var dict = new Dictionary<char, char>(length);
    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
    {
        char c1 = s1[i];
        char c2 = s2[i];
        bool contained = dict.TryGetValue(c1, out char c);
        if (contained && c2 != c)
        {
            return false;
        }

        dict[c1] = c2;
    }

    return true;
}
```

Here are your samples. Note that i use `UniqueMapping` twice(if `true` after 1st):

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var items = new List<string[]> { new[]{ "aab", "ttd" }, new[] { "tab", "ttd" }, new[] { "ala bala portocala", "cuc dcuc efghficuc" }, new[] { "ala bala portocala", "cuc dcuc efghijcuc" } };
    foreach (string[] item in items)
    {
        bool result = UniqueMapping(item[0], item[1]);
        if(result) result = UniqueMapping(item[1], item[0]);
        Console.WriteLine($"Word 1 <{item[0]}> Word 2 <{item[1]}> UniqueMapping? {result}");
    }
}
```

.NET Fiddle: https://dotnetfiddle.net/4DtIyH

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, I still got a little problem. I used the code, but it says "Program does not contain a static 'Main' method suitable for an entry point". What is the meaning? Can you help me, please?

Comment: @LaurențiuCozma: of course you need to add the method to your Program class. Keep your main method and add my second code snippet there.

Comment: My code does not work properly, if I keep my code I still get the wrong answer.

Comment: You can remove your code

Comment: It works when I write „ala bala portocala” and „cuc dcuc efghficuc”, but it does not work when I write „ala bala portocala” and „cuc dcuc efghijcuc” (I should get it "false" but it remains true).

Comment: @LaurențiuCozma: No, it works always, you haven't used my code. I have tested it now. See this .NET fiddle with the same code as in my answer: https://dotnetfiddle.net/4DtIyH